# Angular 4, browser refresh page restarts everything

Tags: angular, browser, refresh

Working on a Angular 4 web app using JSON Web Token to authenticate all pages. A JWT token is saved in an auth service variable. If the token is null then redirect to a login page. When login successes, save a token in the auth service variable. My problem is, when browser refresh page button is clicked, the whole app is reloaded, ngOnInit() of AppComponent is called and everything is restarted, as a result the current page is lost and login page shows up. What I want is, refresh only the component that is being displayed without restart AppComponent. How can I do this? Is the browser refresh action under control?

Comment: You can save the token in e.g. LocalStorage, but the app will always restart when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe. then is there any way I can tell if AppComponent ngOnInit() is called because of refresh or normal launch?

Comment: As far as the app is concerned a refresh is a *"normal launch"*.

Comment: Thanks. You answered all my questions.